# Does maximum vocabulary count is related to word vector dimensions in Glove model

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I have implemented Glove model following the implementation from this link https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/tree/master/src. I have specified max vocab parameter as 100000000 while generating vocab.txt file and word vector dimensions as 100 while training the model and generated vectors.txt with 100 dimensions.
When I am trying to evaluate word_analogy.py from eval folder in the above link, I am getting following error

```
  File "C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/JAYASHREE/Documents/1 billion words/word_analogy.py", line 77, in <module>
    W, vocab, ivocab = generate()

  File "C:/Users/JAYASHREE/Documents/1 billion words/word_analogy.py", line 32, in generate
    W[vocab[word], :] = v

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 66 to array axis with dimension 100
```

I want to know whether parameters specified during vocabulary file creation has an effect on dimensions of vectors file

Comment: Why is this tagged in [c]?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala files are generated from C application

Comment: 66 is not 100. it happens in your code. use pdb